# Retrieving complex numbers from simultaneous equation

Tags: complex-numbers, systems-of-equations

I have a question where **a** and **b** are complex roots of the equation:

$\ 2z^2 -4z + 5 = 0$

I have boiled down using sum of the product of the roots thats this system of equations is true:

**a** + **b** = 2

**ab** = 2.5

I have put the two equations into Wolfram and found that it returns complex solutions (as the lines do not physically cross when plotted).

How can I show how to find **a** & **b** through standard further maths a-level working :)

Thanks

Comment: Do you know how to solve a regular quadratic equation? Quadratic formula?

Comment: @Dylan ah right sorry, when its worded into a question and the question before has simultaneous equations before, it's not particular clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do the following:$$a+b=2\implies a=2-b\\ab=2.5\implies (2-b)b=2.5\implies-b^2+2b-2.5=0$$ now solving squared equation:$$b_{1,2}=\frac{-\overbrace{2}^{b}\pm\sqrt{\overbrace{2^2}^{b^2}-4\times\overbrace{-1}^a\times\overbrace{-2.5}^c}}{2\times\overbrace{2}^a}$$

note that the $\overbrace{}^b$ is not the same $b$ as the one we are looking for, but the coefficient of the first degreepart

Answer (score 1):

The roots of the equation $2z^2-4z+5=0$ are $$z=\frac{4 \pm \sqrt{-24}}{2\cdot 2}=\frac{4\pm 2i\sqrt{6}}{4}=\frac{2\pm i\sqrt{6}}{2}.$$ Both the solutions are complex numbers: $\mathbf{a,b}\in \mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

yes you will get the Solutions $$x_{1,2}=1\pm \frac{1}{2}i\sqrt{6}$$ where $i^2=-1$